# postgresql select different query for specific value on column

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE dtvs_risk_analizine_girmeme_tanimi_t
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  aktif boolean NOT NULL,
  price1 double precision,
  price2 double precision,
  priceoperator integer,
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE dtvs_risk_analizine_girmeme_tanimi_t OWNER TO postgres;
```

hello oll my table like on the up side. 
I have a price and I have many rules on the price column.
I want to get all the column id value for my price value.

If priceopetaror is 0 then price1 is bigger then my price
else if priceopetaror is 1 then price1 is smaller then my price
else if ........

How I get all the row numbers for these rows.

Comment: This is a very confusing question. I think you may be using "then" in places you mean "than"? It would help to give some sample data and the results you'd like to see.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting help building an if statement in sql

```
SELECT if(priceopetaror = 0, 'Bigger', if(priceopetaror = 1, 'Smaller', '')) as 'Some Column Name' from dtvs_risk_analizine_girmeme_tanimi_t
```

at this point you have all rows and a string containing what you have specified as your desired value.  You can now add a where statement to the end of your query.

```
where priceopetaror = 0 or priceopetaror = 1
```

This will ensure you only get rows that have a value of 0 or 1

If you need additional assistance please post additional criteria.